# Error in Haskell code containing tuples

Tags: haskell, tuples

I have been trying to create a function in Haskell that will take a non-negative value which corresponds to minutes and return it in the format (days,hours,minutes) e.g. 4000 minutes will give (2, 18, 39).

My code keeps returning the error "`` file:.\prac0.hs:27 - Syntax error in input (unexpected `|') ``" on load.

Here is my code:

```
dayshoursmins :: Int->(Int,Int,Int)
dayshoursmins n = (x,y,z)
    | n==0 = 0  
    | n`div`1440 =>1 = x && dayshoursmins(n`mod`1440)
    | n`div`60 < 24 = y && dayshoursmins(n`mod`60)
    | n < 60 = z
```

Comment: Any chance you're mixing tabs with spaces accidentally?

Comment: @JanDvorak: this has nothing to do with tabs/spaces: note a pipe is placed after the `=`...

Comment: Oh well... Time to close as a brain typo, then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pipe (`|`) is used as a *guard*, what you need is a `where` clause I think:

```
dayshoursmins :: Int->(Int,Int,Int)
dayshoursmins n = (d,h,m)
    where d = div n 1440
          dm = mod n 1440
          h = div dm 60
          m = mod dm 60
```

Running this with `ghci` gives:

```
*Main> dayshoursmins 2016
(1,9,36)
```

I don't really understand your code: it does seem to mix all kinds of concepts. After the `=` operator, you cannot put *guards* anymore.

Comment: The constructs introduced by `|` are simply called "guards". [Pattern guards](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#pattern-guards) are a more advanced form of guards, which GHC implements as an extension.

Comment: Ah, thank you. May I ask why the "dm" ? Win hugs is now displaying a new error message: 
Type error in application
*** Expression     : dm mod 60
*** Term           : dm
*** Type           : Int
*** Does not match : a -> b -> c

Comment: `dm` stands for *days modulo*. It is simply used as an intermediate result for `h` and `m`.

Comment: @naturesenshi: that was a small error in the first version. Please use the version edited six minutes ago.

Comment: Ah great!! Thank you!! Works a charm!